# String diff on punctuation: is preg_split the answer?

Tags: php, regex, diff

http://piratepad.net/IY48xXzsys (modified by Peter West, from the original here: http://paulbutler.org/archives/a-simple-diff-algorithm-in-php/)

Currently a diff between "I think, therefore" and "I think therefore" will produce:

```
I < del >think,< /del >< ins >think< /ins > therefore
```

I would like it to produce:

```
I think< del >,< /del > therefore
```

I think the answer would be to include the comma as a separate entity in the array that results from the `preg_split` function.  I tried to play around with parenthesis, but could not get this to work. Can you help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that adding a comma to the delimiters in the call to `split` will do it.